# SQL Table Update with join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, Table1 and Table2, which have N no. of columns. I need to update Table1 based on Table2. I want to update all the columns in Table1 which are listed in a single column in Table2.

**E.G**

```
    Table1   A B C D E . . .
             1 2 3 4 5 . . .
             7 6 5 4 3 . . .

    Table2   X Y Col_Nam Col_Value
             1 2    C       8
             1 2    D       9
             7 6    E       10
             7 6    C       20
             . .    .       .
             . .    .       .
```

Update all the columns in Table1 which are listed in Table2 when matching the following condition          Table1.A = Table2.X
                   and  Table1.B = Table2.Y

The Platform is SQL Server.
What I am looking for is a solution which is dynamic, because I don't know the column names which I am going to update. Table1 can have N no. of columns which need to be updated. I tried the following using Cursor.

```
DECLARE @s Varchar(MAX), @key1 VARCHAR(MAX), @key2 VARCHAR(MAX), @Cname VARCHAR(MAX), @CValue VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE crs CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM Table2
OPEN crs;
FETCH NEXT FROM crs inTO @key1,@key2,@Cname,@Cvalue;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
set @s =
                'Update T1 SET ' +  @FieldName + ' = ''' + @FieldValue +
        ''' from Table1 T1' +
        ' where T1.A = '''  + @key1 +
        ''' and T1.B = ''' + @key2 

exec(@s)


    FETCH NEXT FROM crs inTO @key1,@key2,@Cname,@Cvalue;

END

CLOSE crs
DEALLOCATE crs
```

Somehow it is not working and I want to put a default value for all those records which are not matching the where condition.

Any other solution or help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is a standard way to do it but a particular platform (SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, mySql etc) have "shortcuts" that are faster.  What platform?

Comment: On a related note: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68169/is-updation-a-correct-word

Comment: @JamesMohler I made an updation to the title.

Comment: This problem has been discussed a lot of times, please before posting this, you should have done a better search. Also you should specify the platform, it's important.

Comment: @Hogan because before should be specified the sql platform.

Comment: @GastonF. - That answer has examples for 5 platforms.

Comment: @Hogan, that is correct, but the user typically does not seek an answer for all platforms, in this case I'm sure he's just looking for a single platform. The questions should be more specific and should not lead to ambiguities.

Answer (score 1):

**warning**: before using any dynamic SQL, read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). In your case, if user have access to table2, it could be hacked by writing sql code into col_name.

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a12d/11)

```
declare @X int, @Y int, @stmt nvarchar(max), @params nvarchar(max)

select @params = '@X int, @Y int'

declare table_cursor cursor local fast_forward for
    select distinct X, Y from Table2

open table_cursor
while 1 = 1
begin
    fetch table_cursor into @X, @Y
    if @@fetch_status <> 0 break

    select @stmt = null
    select @stmt = 
        isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + 
        Col_Name + ' = ' + cast(Col_Value as nvarchar(max))
    from Table2
    where X = @X and Y = @Y

    select @stmt = 'update Table1 set ' + @stmt + ' where A = @X and B = @Y'

    exec dbo.sp_executesql
        @stmt = @stmt,
        @params = @params,
        @X = @X,
        @Y = @Y
end
close table_cursor
deallocate table_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL way to do this requires correlated subqueries:

```
update table1
    set C = coalesce((select max(col_value)
                      from Table2 t2
                      where table1.A = t2.X and table1.B = t2.Y and
                            t2.Col_Name = 'A'
                     ), C),
        D = coalesce((select max(col_value)
                      from Table2 t2
                      where table1.A = t2.X and table1.B = t2.Y and
                            t2.Col_Name = 'D'
                     ), D)
```

Some SQL engines allow joins.  The following would be a method to use with MySQL:

```
update table1 join
       (select X, Y, max(case when col_name = 'C' then col_value end) as C,
               max(case when col_name = 'D' then col_value end) as D
        from table2
        group by X, Y
       ) t2
       on t2.X = table1.A and t2.Y = table2.Y
    set C = coalesce(t2.C, C),
        D = coalesce(t2.D, D)
```

In both cases the `coalesce()` is intended to keep the current value, when there is no match.  If you want `NULL` with no match, then just remove the `coalesce()`.

EDIT

In SQL Server, the syntax for an update/join is slightly different:

```
update table1 join
    set C = coalesce(t2.C, C),
        D = coalesce(t2.D, D)
    from table1 join
         (select X, Y, max(case when col_name = 'C' then col_value end) as C,
                 max(case when col_name = 'D' then col_value end) as D
          from table2
          group by X, Y
         ) t2
         on t2.X = table1.A and t2.Y = table2.Y;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon , Thank you for your response , I have updated my question with more details, any help will be appreciated.